# Why is my ASP.NET MVC route configuration causing an HTTP 404 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

The issue arises with a map route I have added to my RouteConfig.cs file, which maps routes to my Topic controller.

Here's my RegisterRoutes method, from global.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ArticleByTitle",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{title}/{category}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Topic", action = "Get", category = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The Topic controller contains the specified action method:

```
namespace Wiki.Controllers
{
    public class TopicController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Get(string title, string category)
        {
            var topics = this.GetTopicsList();
            var count = topics.Count(t => t.Category.Equals(category, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                          && t.Title.Equals(title, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (count > 1)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Resolve", new { title = title });
            }

            if (count == 0)
            {
                return new HttpNotFoundResult();
            }

            var selectedTopic = this.GetTopicsList().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Title.Equals(title, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            return RedirectToAction("Display", new { topic = selectedTopic });
        }

    }
}
```

However, this method is never invoked. Instead, I am receiving an HTTP 404 error when I attempt to reach it through a link in the application that looks like this:

```
<a href="/topic/display/MyTopic">MyTopic</a>
```

I am assuming that there is something wrong with my routing configuration, but for the life of me, I can't see what it is. Could someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: In your href you're missing the action (which in your case is 'Get')

Comment: @Dimitar, Can you make this an actual answer? This is the solution I was looking for. It's always something *simple, stupid, and obvious.* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your `href` you're missing your action (which in your case is `Get`)

Answer (score 1):

For the Get action to be invoked your URL would need to look like this:

```
<a href="/topic/get/mytitle/mycategory"></a>
```

You should also generate the link by using the Html ActionLink helper like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyTopic", "Get", "Topic", new { title = "sometitle"}, null)
```

Comment: The category is an optional parameter.

Comment: <a href="/topic/get/mytitle"></a> would also work. What I'm saying is your orginal URL is mapped to the display action, which means it will never call the Get action unless you have some sort of redirect in the Display action that you have not shown in your code.

Comment: Further, the action won't even enter the picture if the controller is never invoked.

Comment: If I set a breakpoint in the first line of the Get action, it's never hit.

Comment: The first parameter in the URL maps to the controller name, the second parameter maps to the action. Your original URL is mapping to the Topic controller Display action. /topic/display.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following syntax

```
action="@Url.Action("Go", "Home")"
```

for your HREF link.